# Toggling icon on button in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, button, meteor, icons

I have a table created in meteor that is expandable. The initial button that is pressed to expand the table has a plus icon on it. Once the table is expanded I wan't to be able to make the icon on the button change to a minus sign. Basically I want the icon to toggle between a plus and minus sign depending on if the table is expanded or collapsed.

My template for the button:

```
<template name="expandButton">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-circle">
    <span id="expand" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</template>
```

The template is callled in the html and works as expected.

My most recent attemp has been trying to use an event for getting the icon to switch from the plus sign to the minus sign:

```
Template.expandButton.events({
  'click #expand'(event) {
    event.toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  }
})
```

I have also tried a couple other ways, but nothing has worked. I would like to know if this is close to being a way of doing this or if this is completely wrong. And if it is the wrong way to do this, how should I go about doing it?

Thanks for any help. It is appreciated.

Comment: try `$(event.target).toggleClass`. The `event` object is an, umh, event, not a DOM node.

Comment: Ok so that fixed it, but It only switches the icon if the icon is pressed. So if I press outside the icon, just on the button, it still doesn't switch. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: If you were using React then it would be so simple with State management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Meteor you have to bind the events on right places. you want to bind the click event to button.

```
<template name="expandButton">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-circle" id="expandBtn">
        <span id="expand" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
</template>
```

and here is your event

```
Template.expandButton.events({
    'click #expandBtn'(event, temp) {
        temp.$('#expand').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    }
})
```

Please also note that in meteor events, the first argument is `event` and second is `template` so using `temp.$` is more efficient then parsing the complete dom i.e `$(#id)`